# AsyncTask wont terminate

Tags: android, google-maps, android-asynctask

I am trying to use Async Tasks to render and add markers to a google map but the map never stops loading. Am I using the doInBackground and onPostExecute methods correctly? I'm not really sure how to fix this issue.

Here are my two async task classes

```
public class addMarkers extends AsyncTask<Void, String, GoogleMap> {

    String result;
    ProgressDialog pdia;

    protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {

        pdia.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected GoogleMap doInBackground(Void... params) {
        publishProgress("Loading..."); // Calls onProgressUpdate()
        MapsFragment.HOME = new LatLng(30.284273, -97.744777);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HOME));
        return mGoogleMap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
        pdia = ProgressDialog.show(getContext(), "Please wait", "Loading data from database.", true, false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... text) {

    }
}

public class renderMap extends AsyncTask<Void, String, View>{
    ProgressDialog pdia;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ViewGroup container;

    renderMap(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container){
        this.inflater = inflater;
        this.container = container;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        pdia.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected View doInBackground(Void... params) {
        publishProgress("Loading..."); // Calls onProgressUpdate()
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);
        return mView;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
        pdia = ProgressDialog.show(getContext(), "Please wait", "Loading data from database.", true, false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... text) {

    }
}
```

And here is what my screen looks like when I try to load the map.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

We should not do UI operations in other thread, should do UI operations only in UI threads, so remove both Async task and add your code in UI thread.